# Can we say "how to not to be..."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, infinitives, to-infinitive

> You should learn about how to not to be egoistic.

2 people (both are English native speakers) have corrected my sentence above,

> 1. You should learn how not to be egoistical.
> 2. You should learn how to not to be so egoistic.

One of them told me that *about* isn't necessary because it makes no grammatical sense. The thing that I still have a doubt about is the usage of **how to not to be**. As you can see above, two people have different perspectives as to how I use the phrase. I read from [here](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/to-not-be-or-not-to-be), that (as per my understanding) writing **to not be** and **not to be** would be possible.

The question is, do I still have to put **to** after **how**?

Comment: "(How) **to be** or (how) **not to be**" that is the question." "(Where) **To sleep** or (where) **not to sleep**?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is correct; the second one is unnecessarily wordy and therefore incorrect. “**How to not to be**” is, as far as I know, not a valid sentence structure or phrasing and should not be used. You can say “**how to be**” or “**how not to be**” but “**how to not to be**” does not make any sense.